# EventStore - what version to use?

Tags: event-sourcing, eventstoredb

- Could any one explain why there are 2 actual versions of `EventStore` (20.6.1 and 5.0.9)?
- What is the difference between them ?
- What version for what goals should we use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to add a couple of things to the answers provided by my colleagues.

First, v5.0.9 and v20.10 are both LTS (long-term support). Look at Ubuntu (already mentioned by Chris), it has a few currently supported LTS versions. By definition, LTS versions will get fixes, that's why v5 releases keep coming these days.

Then, v20+ has a lot of major changes, some were mentioned by Joao, and I'd like to list them all:

- Secure by default. v20+ expect to run with SSL, unlike v5, which is insecure by default. v20 can run in the insecure mode for non-production load, but it disables both authentication and authorisation.
- gRPC is the new norm. We want to phase out TCP and ATOM Pub protocols. gRPC clients are available for quite a few tech stacks, not only .NET. We have supported clients for .NET, Java, NodeJS, Rust, Huskel, and more might be coming.
- v20 doesn't use Mono, which still has quite a few internal issues. It makes v20+ more stable and more performant.

Comment: Thank you! Acocrding to your answer it looks like it is better to use v20 for new project, correct?

Comment: 21.2 is the latest version, the latest LTS is 20.10. The main thing for new projects is the gRPC protocol, which is definitely better to use today as TCP will be phased out at some point.

Comment: I remember when i was constantly bugging them that HTTP is an idiotic idea for such a system, and they had 0 plans for grpc.. good thing they changed their mind

Comment: gRPC didn't exist until 2015, and EventStore is older than that.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference between 20.x and 5.x is the addition of the gRPC transport in 20.6.0.  All of the other transports - TCP and ATOM - have been deprecated. Eventually 5.x will go out of support.

Comment: HTTP Atom Pub and TCP _will_ be deprecated. Users can still explicitly enable TCP and Atom Pub using settings.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Event Store offers support on the 2 most recent major versions to allow users with production deployments a reasonable support window before needing to upgrade.

The Release naming convention convention recently changed to a [year].[month] model similar to what [ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle) does.

So the 20.6.1 version is simply the next release and would have been called 6.0.1 in the old version naming convention.

You should target the current [20.10.0](https://www.eventstore.com/downloads) release for all uses.
[Versioning strategy writeup](https://www.eventstore.com/blog/new-version-strategy)

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer!

"convention recently changed to a [year].[month]".
In such case why official site says:

"EventStoreDB 5.0.9 - Released: 15 Oct 2020
EventStoreDB 20.10.0 (LTS) Released: 16 Dec 2020"?

Comment: Added a link to the release write to the answer